# blur, filters and noise

Tags: image, filter, blur

I am learning how to image manipulation without any book or anything, just the basic internet searches and mathematical knowledge of calculus and linear algebra.

I am using the grey-scale of 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B, which works wonderfully of scaling a picture into grey, but I am having a problem when trying to blur a photo, I am using the following [kernel matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2w0d.jpg) and I am receiving noise that I have no idea how to deal with.

And with a [blurred grey-scaled](http://puu.sh/nKbZZ/8fc444b811.jpg) version of the photo, you can see, I get some sort of noise (?), looking at her face and in the background; there is this areas where it's different than what it's supposed to be, my question is, why do I get that? how to get rid of it and why does it happen.

Also, does any one recommends a book I can read on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To have a better chance of getting your question answered, you should add tags for the language you are using. And add some code to understand where you blurred-gray scale image is coming from. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about which language you are comfortable in however the following book in C is an excellent first text to go through

[Image Processing in C](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/cips2ed.pdf)

Also have to recommend [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library which has wrappers in most languages

Comment: I am familiar with C, although writing this in Java, I am not using any libraries and writing everything from scratch, this book is good, thank you; however can you help me why do I get areas of "irregularities"? how to get rid of it?